# Creating async modbus server python problem

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am new to Python and trying to create a modbus server with pymodbus module. I follow tutorial on [link](https://github.com/SimplyAutomationized/modbus-tcp-tutorials/blob/master/pi_gpio_modbus_tcp_slave.py), but when I run script I got an error:

```
$ python2.7 server1.py    
INFO:pymodbus.server.async:Starting Modbus TCP Server on 192.168.1.100:502    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "server1.py", line 83, in <module>    
StartTcpServer(context, address=("192.168.1.100", 502))    
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymodbus/server/async.py",     
line 255, in StartTcpServer    
reactor.listenTCP(address[1], factory, interface=address[0])    
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-     
packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 495, in listenTCP    
p.startListening()    
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py",     
line 1363, in startListening    
raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)    
twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on     
192.168.1.100:502: [Errno 13] Permission denied.
```

Anyone can help me solve my problem, Thanks in advance.

---

[**UPDATE**]:

```
$ sudo python2.7 server1.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "server1.py", line 12, in <module>     
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer    
ImportError: No module named pymodbus.server.async    

$ python -V    
Python 2.7.13

$ sudo python server1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "server1.py", line 12, in <module>
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer
ImportError: No module named pymodbus.server.async
```

I tried "sudo" already and got an error, it looks like when I use "sudo" the modules isn't on right spot...

Comment: Please put on the `sudo python -V` result, on your question as an UPDATE

Comment: Also put on `which python` and `sudo which python` result on your question.

Comment: You will have to check your `PYTHONPATH` and set it appropriately when using `sudo` or if you are not restricted to use PORT 502, you can edit the file and use another port > 1024 , which doesn't require super user permissions.

Comment: Found that my python modules are located at `$/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` so i need to change shebang from  `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/.local/lib/env python` and move my script to `$/.local/lib/python2.7`

Comment: @TilenŠpacapan I updated my answer.

Comment: @TilenŠpacapan I've added [UPDATE 2] in my answer to deal with your new problem: `No module named pymodbus.server.async` which is due to different pymodbus version.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo` permission:

```
$ sudo python2.7 server1.py
```

Or if your `python` is linked to the *Python 2.7* as the following:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.14
```

Then try it:

```
$ sudo python server1.py
```

---

[UPDATE]:

The following lines result must be same:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ sudo which python
/usr/bin/python
```

If your codes run in the same machine, you can use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` IP instead of machine IP.

---

[**NOTE**]:

If your OS is ***nix** system based, and you have the `ufw` firewall, doing the following command:

```
$ sudo ufw disable
```

---

[UPDATE 2]:

To dealing with this error `ImportError: No module named pymodbus.server.async`

you should use

```
import pymodbus.server.asynchronous
```

instead of

```
import pymodbus.server.async
```

in the new version of `pymodbus` library.